# Proplems due to Copying a WPF Solution - InitializeComponent() not found

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, wpf-controls, solution

I have a **Working** and **Compileable** WPF-Solution in a which I needed to copy to another directory.

*Now I experience the following Problem, which I nowhere found similar on the web:*

In some Projects every `UserControl` I created, isnt compileable anymore. Somehow Terms like `DataContext` or `InitializeComponent()` *"do not exist in the current context"*.

Usually this is a case of wrong namespaces, or classnaming between the **xaml** and **xaml.cs**. As my code is all compileable in the original repo, this can not be the case. I've also checked that **build action** is set to **Page**, which is also a common issue in this case.

As I've found out, even newly created UserControls have the same problems. So I compared the projectfiles from the source and targed destination, which seemed to have no difference at all.

At this point I'll ask the community. Have you ever experienced a similar problem? What do you think i could check, too?

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there's been a reference inside my project which was wrong but that wasn't reported.

I solved my problem with readding all my references even if they were meant as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `x:Class` property on the pasted `UserControl` and make sure it matches the fully qualified class name of the codebehind

for instance in you have the following in `MyUserControl.xaml.cs`:

```
...

namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class MyUserControl: UserControl
    {
        public MyUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Then make sure the you have `x:Class="MyApp.MyUserControl` in your `MyUserControl.xaml` file

Comment: thank you for your response. As I mentioned this is a common problem, but doesn't match my case because it works and doesnt work if the source is copied.